# A few questions about the function sending a Borel set U to integration over U

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, differential-geometry

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathcal{F}:= \{f: \mathbb{R^n \to \mathbb{R}} \mid f\text{ is integrable w.r.t. } \mu\}$. Define a map $\iota:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\setminus\mathcal{N}\mapsto \mathcal{F}^*, U \mapsto \int_U (\cdot)d\mu$, where $\mathcal{N}$ is the set of $\mu$-null-sets. My questions are:

1. I assume $\iota$ is not surjective. Is that so ?
2. Under which circumstances does an arbitraty functional $L\in\mathcal{F}^*$ have a preimage under $\iota$ ?
3. Can $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\setminus\mathcal{N}$ be equipped with a topology/smooth structure such that $\iota$ becomes an embedding ?
4. Are there interesting resources concerning this topic ?

Comment: 1. You cannot get the zero functional in the image of $\iota$, I think.  2 almost never I think. To get all functionalisme one varies over $\mu$ but fixed $\mu$ doesn’t allow for a lot. Just a hunch though. 3. Well, what topology are you putting on $\mathcal F^\ast$? 4 not that I know of. It’s a bizarre idea IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your space $\mathcal F$ is usually denoted  $L^1(\mathbb R^n,\mu )$ and, if you are denoting by $\mathcal{F}^*$ its dual
as a normed space, equipped with the the norm
$$
  \|f\|_1 = \int_{{\mathbb R}^n}|f(x)|\,d\mu(x),
  $$
then $L^1(\mathbb R^n,\mu )^*\simeq L^\infty (\mathbb R^n,\mu )$.  According to this isomorphism your functional $\iota _U$ corresponds
to the characteristic function $\chi_U$.  So, another way to view $\iota $ is
$$
  \iota:U\in  \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) \mapsto \ \chi _U\in  L^\infty (\mathbb R^n,\mu ).
  $$

Your question (1) is therefore asking whether or not every bounded measurable function coincides with a
characteristic function a.e.,
and I suppose it has now become  obvious that the answer is no.

The answer to (2) can also be deduced  from the above formulation, as it is essentially asking which measurable
functions are characteristic functions.

Regarding (3), I have not seen any discussion on topology/smooth structures making $\iota $ an embedding, but one could
easily define an ad-hoc one by borrowing from the corresponding structures of $L^\infty (\mathbb R^n,\mu )$.